# Сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку enter было действие как при клике

Tags: jquery

Не могу понять куда мне прописать `keydown`
пока делаю так но не работает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.which == 13) {
         var  message = $("#message").val();
         var idVal = $("#id-val").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "send.php",  
                data: {message: message, 
                      idVal: idVal},  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){ 

               $('#message').val('');
                   
                } 

            });  
            }
        });
   });
```

А вот при клике все работает если делать так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#clickButtonForm").bind("click", function show() {
         var  message = $("#message").val();
         var idVal = $("#id-val").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "send.php",  
                data: {message: message, 
                      idVal: idVal},  
                cache: false,  
                success: function(html){ 

               $('#message').val('');
                   
                }  
            });  
        });
   });
```

html выглядит так

```html
    <form class="input-group"  style="margin-top: 5px;" action="" >
      <input type="text" name="message" value=""  id="message"  class="form-control teo-two" placeholder="Search for...">
       <input type="hidden" name="id-val" id="id-val" value="1,2">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="clickButtonForm" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </form>
```

как сделать, чтобы все работало при клике и при нажатии на enter?

Comment: А где должен быть фокус при нажатии на Enter, чтобы ваша магия работала? В `#message` ? Может, вам проще тогда событие `submit` обрабатывать?

Comment: почти но не совсем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил

```html
function submit_handler(form) {
 
 return false;
}
```

и в форму `<form class="input-group" style="margin-top: 5px;" action="" onsubmit="return submit_handler(this)" >`
событие теперь submit обрабатываю

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
       alert(e.which);
    }
};
```

Comment: так не подходит пробовал + как клик срабатывать будет